# Post build status before waiting for node using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

We use jenkins together with a gitlab instance for source code management.
In my Jenkinsfile I can use steps to set the build status which will then be displayed in gitlab using

```
updateGitlabCommitStatus name: "build", state: "running"
```

This works fine within the stages. However, I would like to set the build status to "pending" at the very beginning, so that if a build job needs to wait until the the node it is supposed to run on becomes available (i.e. no stages are executed). Otherwise gitlab will show an error that the connection to the CI is not working.

Is there a way to make this possible, i.e. set the build status before a build node has been acquired.

In the jenkins job it looks like this:

```
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
```

and I would like to have something like this:

```
[Pipeline] node
[Update commit status to pending]
Still waiting to schedule task
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin perhaps is written to take advantage of using a node and the jenkins 'steps' this includes. So in order to do this before assuming a node you would have to write the api calls yourself in a pure groovy sense.

We do this in order to populate a dropdown with artifacts from artifactory. E.g. this is out Artifactory getRequest method:

```
// Artifactory Get Request - Consume in other methods
Object getRequest(url_string){

    URL url = url_string.toURL()

    // Open connection
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()

    connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuthString())

    // Open input stream
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
    @NonCPS
    json_data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(inputStream.text)
    // Close the stream
    inputStream.close()

    return json_data
}
```

Note, even when doing this, you will need to use the @NonCPS annotation for anything that creates a serializable object.

If would be a matter of reading the API's, organising credentials and making the necessary calls.